# jQuery custom content scroller after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found here a lot of questions on this matter but small number of answers.
Some of the answers were `advanced:{ updateOnContentResize: true }`, and I tried it, it didn't work. Also, one of the answers were reinitializing `.mCustomScroll` function on ajax success but it didn't work for me at all.
Is there general solution for this or I should try some other customizable scroll libraries?

Comment: Can you give more details? What do you mean with custom content scroller?

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: so, you want to use that plugin after an ajax call? did you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried two solutions that i mentioned, and it didn't work for me. Also I tried using callback, dead end too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the content on elements that already have custom scrollbar(s), you need to add/append the new content inside the .mCSB_container element (instead directly to the element you called mCustomScrollbar function). 
Example:

```
//scrollbar initialization 
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar();

//at some point later on (within another script, function, ajax call etc.)
$(".content .mCSB_container").append("new content...");
//or targeting a specific .mCSB_container element (usefull with nested scrollbars)
$("#mCSB_1_container").append("new content...");
```

Comment: can this be depicted inside an example please, because I dont quite understand how to implement this.